# Facebook like load new posts in meteor

Tags: meteor

I'm in the process of learning meteor. I followed the tutorial to create [microscope](http://meteor-book-chapter14-2.meteor.com). If some one submits a post meteor will re render the template for all users. This could be very annoying if there are hundreds of posts then the user will come back to the top of the page and loose track of where he was. I want to implement something similar to what facebook has. When a new post is submitted template isn't rendered rather, a button or link will appear. Clicking it will cause the template to re-render and show the new posts.

I was thinking of using `observeChanges` on the collection to detect any changes and it does stop the page from showing new posts but only way to show them is to reload the page.

```
Meteor.publish('posts', function(options) {
  var self = this, postHandle = null;

  var initializing = true;

  postHandle = Posts.find({}, options).observeChanges({
    added: function(id, post) {

      if (initializing){
          self.added('posts', id, post);
      } 
    },
    changed: function(id, fields) {
      self.changed('posts', id, fields);
    }
  });

  self.ready();
  initializing = false;
  self.onStop(function() { postHandle.stop(); });
});
```

Is this the right path to take? If yes, how do I alert the user of new posts? Else, what would be a better way to implement this?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

This is a tricky question but also valuable as it pertains to a design pattern that is applicable in many instances. One of the key aspects is wanting to know that there is new data but not wanting to show it (yet) to the user. We can also assume that when the user does want to see the data, they probably don't want to wait for it to be loaded into the client (just like Facebook). This means that the client still needs to cache the data as it arrives, just not display it immediately.

Therefore, you probably **don't** want to restrict the data displayed in the publication - because this won't send the data to the client. Rather, you want to send all the (relevant) data to the client and cache it there until it is ready.

The easiest way involves having a timestamp in your data to work from. You can then couple this with a Reactive Variable to only add new documents to your displayed set when that Reactive Variable changes. Something like this (code will probably be in different files):

```
// Within the template where you want to show your data
Template.myTemplate.onCreated(function() {
  var self = this;
  var options = null; // Define non-time options

  // Subscribe to the data so everything is loaded into the client
  // Include relevant options to limit data but exclude timestamps
  self.subscribe("posts", options);

  // Create and initialise a reactive variable with the current date
  self.loadedTime = new ReactiveVar(new Date());

  // Create a reactive variable to see when new data is available
  // Create an autorun for whenever the subscription changes ready() state
  // Ignore the first run as ready() should be false
  // Subsequent false values indicate new data is arriving
  self.newData = new ReactiveVar(false);
  self.autorun(function(computation) {
    if(!computation.firstRun) {
      if(!self.subscriptionsReady()) {
        self.newData.set(true);
      }
    }
  });
});

// Fetch the relevant data from that subscribed (cached) within the client
// Assume this will be within the template helper
// Use the value (get()) of the Reactive Variable
Template.myTemplate.helpers({
  displayedPosts = function() {
    return Posts.find({timestamp: {$lt: Template.instance().loadedTime.get()}});
  },

  // Second helper to determine whether or not new data is available
  // Can be used in the template to notify the user
  newData = function() {
    return Template.instance().newData.get();
});

// Update the Reactive Variable to the current time
// Assume this takes place within the template helper
// Assume you have button (or similar) with a "reload" class
Template.myTemplate.events({
  'click .reLoad' = function(event, template) {
    template.loadedTime.set(new Date());
  }
});
```

I think this is the simplest pattern to cover all of the points you raise. It gets more complicated if you don't have a timestamp, you have multiple subscriptions (then need to use the subscription handles) etc. Hope this helps!

Comment: This doesn't seem to work. It stops the re-rendering but newData is never set to true.

Comment: Sorry. It looks like `subscriptionsReady()` might not be reactive (the documents aren't clear) but the complementary template helper is. Therefore, the autorun will not get triggered. Instead, you may need to use the `ready()` method on the subscription handle or `onReady()` callback within the subscribe function.

Answer (score 0):

As Duncan said in his answer, ReactiveVar is the way to go. I've actually implemented a simple facebook feed page with meteor where I display the public posts from a certain page. I use infinite scroll to keep adding posts to the bottom of the page and store them in a ReactiveVar. Check the sources on github [here](https://github.com/cambrozie/meteor-facebook-feed) and the live demo [here](http://meteor-facebook-feed.icenodes.com/). Hope it helps!